# How would I go about running a javascript code once a week?

Tags: firebase

I am building a website, and I am trying to figure out how I would change a variable in the Firebase Realtime Database every Thursday. I have no idea where to start, and if someone could help me go in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: what I'm doing is searching for a node, and changing that node for everyone in the database on a specific day.

Comment: i would start by looking at what is called cron jobs. You mentioned you use firebase so perhaps this link might be useful? https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html

Comment: You have a bewildering number of options depending on what your level of comfort with various products.  If you're looking for product recommendations, that is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  I suggest posting to a discussion forum such as Reddit if you want to generate ideas and discussion.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase

Comment: There are plenty of ways of solving it starting from running script/app connecting to firebase database directly by cron. Well, it depend on what technologies you are able to use. Take a look also on https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions